# Does the magnetic flux change for a finite square loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

If i have a square loop of a finite length (say 1 meter) and I move it perpendicularly(to the B field) through a uniform magnetic field of infinite extent, would the flux through it change and consequently would an emf be induced in it?
My guess is that no flux change would occur, as the area of the loop through which the magnetic flux passes wont change and neither would the no of field lines through the loop would not change as the field is uniform.
any explanations
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There is no magnetic flux change when you move your square coil in a plane perpendicular to the field B.

Answer (score 1):

> uniform magnetic field of infinite extent.

**B** does not change.

**A** of the square loop does not change.
The loop does not rotate.
So the flux remains constant.

[image]